# Drupal jquery 1.3.2 and jquery ui 1.8.11 - how do I get it to work?

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-ui

I'm running Drupal 6.2, and I just updated the jquery to 1.3.2 via jquery update.  I'm also using the Google CDN of jquery 1.8.11 installed manually into the page template.

This works fine on my test server but when I upload it to the live drupal server, the jquery UI isn't recognized at all, and neither is my jquery UI functions (trying to use draggable).

If you'd like to take a look, please look at http://iomobile.dev.devsu.com - the jquery and related links are in the source code.

Thanks,
Blue

Comment: Either you solved your issue or the issue is not present, I just tried to apply draggable to some elements in your page and all works just fine